# Does this scaled version of a Poisson distribution have a name?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution

I have this probability distribution:

$$P(\{X=x\})=\frac{\lambda^x\exp(-\lambda)}{x!(1-\exp(-\lambda))}$$

where $x\in \mathbb{N}$. If not for this factor $\frac{1}{1-\exp(-\lambda)}$, this would be Poisson distribution. What is its name?

Comment: For what values of $x$? Are you sure the probabilities sum to $1$?

Comment: Hint: what values can $x$ take?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala: Snap!

Comment: You must specify the range of  $x$! Without that, the definition is not precise. We cannot, for instance, decide if the probabilities sum to 1 or not.

Comment: $x\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Where does $\mathbb{N}$ start for you? Nought or one?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$. If that helps it was in example that MVUE can be "nonsense".

Comment: It would have to be $x \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, to make the probabilities sum to one. So the kernel's a Poisson, but a Poisson gives a non-zero probability for a count of nought - the distribution's been clipped, docked, trimmed ... To see where the factor $\frac{1}{1-\exp(-\lambda)}$ comes from, work out the probability of getting a count of nought from a Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the name. It's called "Zero-truncated Poisson distribution".

Source: Johnson L., Kemp A., Kotz S., *Univariate Discrete Distributions* 3rd edition, Wiley,  p. 188

Comment: (+1) Note that $\exp(-\lambda) = \Pr(X=0)$ when $X$ is a Poisson random variable. So the mass function can be recognized as $\frac{\Pr(X=x)}{\Pr(X >0)}=\Pr(X=x \mid x>0)$, the Poisson probability of a count conditional on its being greater than nought.